# String from a list of model not binding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the following property in model:

```
public class QuoteRequestViewModel
{
    public long LeadId { get; set; }

    public AgentQuoteInfoModel GeneralInfo { get; set; }

    public List<TransportQuoteModel> ListTransport { get; set; }
}
```

The TransportQuoteModel is as follows:

```
public class TransportQuoteModel
{
    public string InclusionsId { get; set; }
    public string ExclusionsId { get; set; }
}
```

I have a jquery script:

```
$('.inclusionExclusionMainDiv').each(function (i, obj) {
    selectedInclusions = [6-0,8-0];
    $("#ListTransport_"+i+"__Inclusions").val(selectedInclusions);
})
```

I am running the above jquery code before submiting the form by javascript.

The rendered InclusionsId and ExclusionsId in the cshtml is as below:

```
<input class="selectedInclusion0" id="ListTransport_0__Inclusions"    name="ListTransport[0].Inclusions" type="hidden" value="">
<input class="selectedExclusion0" id="ListTransport_0__Exclusions" name="ListTransport[0].Exclusions" type="hidden" value="">
```

Comment: What should happen? A little bit more context would be nice :)

Comment: Post your controller method where the binding takes place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your rendered html for the inputs is in the correct format but it is referencing a property name which does not exist.

i.e: your rendered html should look like this:

```
<input class="selectedInclusion0" id="ListTransport_0__InclusionsId" name="ListTransport[0].InclusionsId" type="hidden" value="">
<input class="selectedExclusion0" id="ListTransport_0__ExclusionsId" name="ListTransport[0].ExclusionsId" type="hidden" value="">
```

instead of:

```
<input class="selectedInclusion0" id="ListTransport_0__Inclusions" name="ListTransport[0].Inclusions" type="hidden" value="">
<input class="selectedExclusion0" id="ListTransport_0__Exclusions" name="ListTransport[0].Exclusions" type="hidden" value="">
```

then you'll need to change your script appropriately:

```
$("#ListTransport_"+i+"__InclusionsId").val(selectedInclusions);
```